# Which protocol to use if I am writing a multiplayer game server with Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, multiplayer

I am developing a multiplayer game server with Twisted. It's a simple game that on each map there are several players to interact with each other. At the very beginning, I just want to make them move and can be seen by others.

I think most data I need to send back and forth are the movement data, such as direction, speed, etc.

Is there a protocol that Twisted already implements I should use? Is `NetstringReceiver` good for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [AMP](http://amp-protocol.net/).  Twisted includes [a pretty good implementation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html).  You can find an example of using AMP in a 2d game in [the Game project on launchpad](http://launchpad.net/game).

See also this very similar question, [Basic networking with Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961752/basic-networking-with-pygame)

Comment: Really helpful! Though I've already started using AMP before reading this... got answer from IRC ;)